# Efficiency of the unlimited hdf5 files in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dataset, hdf5

As shown in the examples of the [official MATLAB documentation](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/h5write.html), it is possible to write into an infinite `hdf5` file using the following code:

```
h5create('myfile.h5','/DS3',[20 Inf],'ChunkSize',[5 5]);

for j = 1:10
      data = j*ones(20,1);
      start = [1 j];
      count = [20 1];
      h5write('myfile.h5','/DS3',data,start,count);
end
h5disp('myfile.h5');
```

I'm not familiar with the way MATLAB deals with `hdf5` files but is it more efficient to pre-allocate the size of the file?

I have to write a very large dataset, and finding the size of it is a non-trivial task.

Comment: Have you tried testing it? write dump in a hdf5 file without telling the size and telling it, and time it!

Comment: I'm working on it but sometimes according to the size of the data you can get various timings. I am after understanding what is happening in it. I am going to let it run till tomorrow and see what is happening.

Comment: Include the `save` command into your comparison. Using the `-v7.3` format it writes a gzip compressed HDF5 file. It might be the fastest option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**
Writing finite files is faster than writing the same amount of data in an infinite file. However, there is no dynamic reallocation of the entire file when using infinite files and writing the data is still fairly fast.

**Long answer:**
The way the data are stored is explained in the [hdf5 documentation](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/UG/HDF5_Users_Guide-Responsive%20HTML5/index.html#t=HDF5_Users_Guide%2FDatasets%2FHDF5_Datasets.htm%23TOC_5_5_Allocation_of_Spacebc-15&rhtocid=5.3), here is a short quote of it.

> For chunked storage, the data is stored in one or more chunks. Each
>   chunk is a continuous block in the file, but chunks are not
>   necessarily stored contiguously. Each chunk has the same size. The
>   data array has the same nominal size as a contiguous array (number of
>   elements x size of element), but the storage is allo­cated in chunks,
>   so the total size in the file can be larger that the nominal size of
>   the array. See the figure below.

Without using any optimisation as the one cited by Daniel, I tried to write a dummy file containing **200 MB** of data using the following code:

Without using the infinite size:

```
h5create('train.h5','/data',[size_x size_y 3 length(label)]);
h5create('train.h5','/label',[1 length(label)]);

tic
h5write('train.h5','/data', data)
h5write('train.h5','/label', label)
fprintf('Writing finite file :')
toc
```

Using the infinite size:

```
h5create('train.h5','/data',[size_x size_y 3 Inf],'ChunkSize',[size_x size_y 3 56]);
h5create('train.h5','/label',[1 Inf],'ChunkSize',[1 56]);
tic
for ii = 1:round(length(data)/56)
    data_info = h5info('train.h5');
    data_start = [1, 1, 1, data_info.Datasets(1).Dataspace.Size(end)+1];
    data_count = [size_x, size_y, 3, 56];
    label_start = [1, data_info.Datasets(1).Dataspace.Size(end)+1];
    label_count = [1, 56];
    h5write('train.h5', '/data', data(:, :, :, (ii-1)*56+1:ii*56), data_start, data_count);
    h5write('train.h5', '/label', label((ii-1)*56+1:ii*56), label_start, label_count);
end
fprintf('Writing infinite file :')
toc
```

The output in the print in the command window are the following one:

Writing finite file :Elapsed time is 1.924045 seconds.

Writing infinite file :Elapsed time is 11.809602 seconds.

A possible explanation of the time difference come from the computation happening in Matlab to define the chunck parameters.